# Let $F$ be a flat $R$-module, and let $a \in R$ be an eleemnt which is not a zero-diisor. Show that if $ax = 0$ for some $x \in F$ then $x = 0$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $F$ be a flat $R$-module, and let $a \in R$ be an element which is not a zero-divisor. Show that if $ax = 0$ for some $x \in F$ then $x = 0$

I'm not sure why the flatness of $F$ is necessary in this case. Doesn't th result follow simply because $a$ is not a zero-divisor?

Comment: Counterexample with a non-flat module: $R = \mathbb{Z}$, $F = \mathbb{Z} / 2 \mathbb{Z}$, $a = 2$, $x = 1 + 2 \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Since $a$ is not a zero-divisor, we have that $\forall r \in R\, (ar=0 \implies r=0)$. And we need to prove that $\forall x \in \color{red}{F}\, (ax=0 \implies x=0) $. It is not the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiplication by $a$ gives a monomorphism $R\to R$. Now tensor with $F$, which is flat, so preserves monos. We see that multiplication by $a$ is a mono $F\to F$, so $ax=0$ implies $x=0$.